# Printing where the last inserted array position

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I would like to print an array where it states where the "placedPosition", or the parameter's location in the array. This position is the location that the latest number was inserted into the sorted part of the array.It is the same for the "currPosition", but I can figure that out if I get help on the placed. "i" is the placedPosition, and "c" is the "currPosition". It should look something like this:

[image]

I'm really not sure how to go about this, here is the code I have thus far:

```
public static void displaySort(int[] items, int currPosition, int placedPosition) {
    System.out.println("Iteration #"+currPosition);
    String[][] arr = new String[currPosition][currPosition];
    String i="i";
    String c="c";
    String ic="ic";
    System.out.println(arr[placedPosition][placedPosition]=i);
    System.out.println(arr[currPosition][currPosition]=c);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
}
```

Sorting:

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] items) {
    int currentPosition;  // the number of items sorted so far
    int currentItem;   // the value being inserted
    int backwardMovingIndex; // used to find where the current value gets inserted.

    //displaySort(items, 0, 0); // use this call to display the list before the first iteration (iteration 0)

    for (currentPosition = 1; currentPosition < items.length; currentPosition++) // Start with 1 (not 0)
    {
        currentItem = items[currentPosition];
        for (backwardMovingIndex = currentPosition - 1; (backwardMovingIndex >= 0) && (items[backwardMovingIndex] > currentItem); backwardMovingIndex--) // Larger values are moving up
        {
            items[backwardMovingIndex + 1] = items[backwardMovingIndex];
        }
        items[backwardMovingIndex + 1] = currentItem;    // Put the current value in its proper location
        displaySort(items, currentPosition, backwardMovingIndex + 1); // use this call to display the list for all other iterations
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are quite confused.
I think what you are trying to do is keep track of the position in the array of an element over each iteration of a sorting algorithm. firstly you need to show us the sorting algorithm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you need to make sure the numbers are printed out with a fixed number of digits, so instead of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));` try using code like

```
    for (int item : items) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", item);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

To place a an "i" in column i use code like

```
    int i = 1;
    for (int x = 0; x<items.length; x++) {
        if (x == i) {
            System.out.printf("%5s", "i");
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("%5s", "");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
```

The key is using the same value (in this example, 5) for the format specifier controlling the column width in all branches of the loop. If these are arbitrary integers, you might need to use a larger value, such as 10. If you want to get fancy, you can figure out how wide you need to make the columns by looking at the base 10 logrithm of the largest absoulte value in the array. You can then convert an integer into a string of exactly `n` characters with something like
`String.format("%"+n+"d", item)`

To complete your problem add more branches to the if/else structure to check for
 `(x == c)` and `(i == c) && (x == i)`